# Existe algum script que envie email com anexos automáticos?

Tags: php

Quero saber se existe algum script ou se no phpmailer da pra enviar emails com anexos para um usuário.

Comment: Existe o phpmailer e tem exemplos prontos no pacote que pode baixar em  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: E aqui tem um tutorial para configuração https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/tutoriais/php/enviar-email-php-com-phpmailer-smtp/

Answer (score 1):

é a partir da função AddAttachment que tu anexa as coisas ao email no phpmaile. da uma olhada https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial